# Uncertainty of coroutines writing to single socket

Tags: halting-problem, concurrency, tcp

A program runs in a low-spec hardware utilizes coroutines writes to a single socket but how does the socket know when the data should be sent as there could more coroutines writing given **N** time.

I find this problem similar to *The halting problem* even tho contexts are different.

Does anyone know how could be a one find a optimal solution to solve this problem?

Comment: If there were only one routine, how would the socket know when the data should be sent?

Comment: @KyleJones Would there be more routines or just 1 forever?

Comment: @KyleJones If it's one, the socket would send data one by one without waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a buffer limit and a queue.

I knew that this may not answer this question fully but it's the only optimal solution I could find.